# What is wrong with this code? I can't seem to get the bullet to be shot from the rocket

Tags: python, pygame

Basically the rocket moves up and down, stops when it reaches the top or bottom and recognizes that the spacebar is being pressed. However the bullet won't shoot from the ship. I'm new to python and pygame. Anyways here is the code, thank you for any help!:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import*

bg_color = (0, 191, 255)
d_w = 1200
d_h= 800
class Rocket(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Rocket.bmp')
        self.x = 0
        self.y = d_h/2

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 6.5
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            if self.y > 0:
                self.y -= dist
        elif key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            if self.y < 775:
                self.y += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            Bullet.update(Bullet)
    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([2, 5])
        self.image.fill(0, 0, 0)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        """ Move the bullet. """
        self.image = pygame.Surface([2, 5])
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x += 3
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((d_w, d_h))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game Character")
Mario = pygame.image.load('Mario_Sprite.bmp')
rocket = Rocket()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    rocket.handle_keys()
    screen.fill(bg_color)
    rocket.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(72)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bullet.update(Bullet)
```

You're calling `update` statically. You need to create an instance of the class and then update that instance, as in:

```
bullet = Bullet()
...
bullet.update()
```

Comment: Hmmm... It seems like it still won't shoot a bullet. Is it possible that I'm not referencing the class correctly?

Comment: You're going to want to create a container to hold all the bullets you create so you can reference them easier. A list would work just fine in your case. You create a bullet like John says above, then simply add it to the list like follows: bulletList.append(bullet). Then you can update all the bullets in that list easily by saying "for bullet in bulletList: bullet.update(*args)". You can also draw all the images on the screen quite similarly  "for bullet in bulletList: screen.blit(bullet.image,(bullet.rect.x,bullet.rect.y))"